# Strange behavior on xcode6 compiling for iOS7

Tags: ios, ios7, uicollectionview, ios8, xcode6

Recently I updated xcode to version 6.

Until know my application worked perfectly for the iOS 7 on xcode5.

However, now when i run my app in the xcode6 for the iOS 7 i have a totally strange behavior on my collectionViews.

[image]

However in the iOS 8 still works perfectly.
[image]

Any idea what could be leading to this behavior ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Maybe it is related to device orientation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after many hours around the problem , I discovered that the problem came from the cells of colllectionview . 
Although the sizes are correct , it's **contentView** was broken, and causes this strange behavior in iOS7.

The solution from me was add in my custom cell:

```
self.contentView.frame = self.bounds;
self.contentView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
```

I hope it helps someone with the same problem.